# Whether there is easy way to compute $R_{ij}=\frac{1}{2}Rg_{ij}$ in 2-dimension

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

In 2-dimensional Riemann manifold ,Ricci curvature is given by 
$$
R_{ij}=\frac{1}{2}Rg_{ij}
$$
My PDE teachers  teach me to compute it by the way.
$$
R_{11}=g^{ij}R_{1i1j}=g^{22}R_{1212}  \\
R_{12}=g^{21}R_{1221} \\
R_{21}=g^{12}R_{2112}  \\
R_{22}=g^{11}R_{2121}   \\
R=g^{ij}R_{ij}=2g^{11}g^{22}R_{1212}-2g^{12}g^{12}R_{1212}=2R_{1212}
\begin{vmatrix} g^{11} &  g^{12} \\ g^{21} &  g^{22} \end{vmatrix}   \\
\frac{1}{2}Rg_{11}=2R_{1212}g_{11}
\begin{vmatrix} g^{11} &  g^{12} \\ g^{21} &  g^{22} \end{vmatrix}  =2R_{1212}g^{22}\begin{vmatrix} g^{11} &  g^{12} \\ g^{21} &  g^{22} \end{vmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{vmatrix} g^{11} &  g^{12} \\ g^{21} &  g^{22} \end{vmatrix} \\
\frac{1}{2}Rg_{11}=R_{11}
$$

Others are likely , but he thinks there should be easy way ,but I can't work out. Whether there are easy way to compute it ?

Comment: Is the question really, how to compute $R$ efficiently? Or whether there is a faster proof that $R_{ij} = \tfrac{1}{2} R g_{ij}$?

Comment: $R=0$ for surfaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify the calculations by working in an orthonormal frame so that contraction with the metric become standard traces. The only non-zero components of the Riemannian curvature are $$K := R_{1212} = R_{2121} = -R_{1221} = -R_{2112}.$$ Then $$R_{ij} = R_{1i1j} + R_{2i2j}= K\delta_{i2}\delta_{j2} + K \delta_{i1}\delta_{j1} = Kg_{ij}.$$

Taking the trace we get $R = 2K$, and thus $$R_{ij} = \frac12 R g_{ij}.$$